# Cannot connect to non standard port number with Windows command-line ftp (cmd ftp username not show)

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, cmd.exe

I have a Windows 7 IIS - FTP Website on my localhost. Its IP is 192.168.2.77:15555,

I can successfully connect to `ftp://192.168.2.77:15555/` and get the file list after enter username/password  through browser like Chrome.

But when I open `cmd`, and use `ftp 192.168.2.77` or `ftp 192.168.2.77:15555`, the prompt for username/password does not show (which should show in normal procedure)

It changed to `ftp>` directly, and if I execute `ls -al` it tells me I'm not connected:

```
C:\Users\username>ftp 192.168.2.77:15555
Unknown host 192.168.2.77:15555.
ftp> ls -al
Not connected.
ftp>
```

```
C:\Users\username>ftp 192.168.2.77
ftp> ls -al
Not connected.
ftp>
```

What should I do further to connect to FTP through `cmd`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no way to connect to a non-standard port number from [`ftp.exe` command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp).

You have to use the [`open` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-open_1):

```
C:\Users\username>ftp
ftp> open 192.168.2.77 15555
```