# win ftp works in File Explorer, don't work in PowerShell, "unknown host"

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, ftp

Well this is bizarr,
I opened File Explorer (windows 10), did *new network location*, `ftp://192.168.1.103:2121`, a window for the remote FTP server opened up and I DLed some files from the server, no problem. Then I did PowerShell as administrator, turned off windows firewall, and got this:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> ftp
> ftp> open 192.168.1.103:2121
> Unknown host 192.168.1.103:2121

I pinged the server's address and got a valid reply. I downloaded and ran some other ftp client and it worked fine. Please help if you know about this. I need it for a batch program.

Comment: See [Cannot connect to non standard port number with Windows command-line ftp (cmd ftp username not show)](https://superuser.com/q/1248499/213663).

Comment: @Martin Prikryl thanx i'm on it.  
[5 minutes later]  
 uhhh... well it still is telling me "Unknown host"   
here's the script:   
`open ftp://192.168.1.103:2121 
uid 
pw 
binary 
get -transfer=binary z982previous.jpg 
get -transfer=binary z982current.jpg 
disconnect 
` uuuhhhh "End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak".... nope

Comment: This is not `ftp` script, that looks like WinSCP script. Did you switch to WinSCP?

Comment: actually i'm DLing WinSCP right now....

Comment: Well, if you used the script from your comment for `ftp`, then it explains the "Unknown host" error, as `open ftp://192.168.1.103:2121` cannot work with `ftp`.

Comment: ....oh, well maybe that's it. i cut n pasted the script from somewhere. so maybe it will work now for winscp,  DOH

Comment: While I'm of course happy that you have switched to my WinSCP – I do not see why you didn't try what I have suggested by the first link (`open 192.168.1.103 2121`).

Comment: [5 more minutes] ok i got it straightened out. using WinSCP and the script is working. Guess i shoulda gone to the "Support for Dimensia" forum.

Comment: And THANX A LOT for that program, now i can get back to work:-)